# Variance of two dependent variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm trying to find a variance of two dependent variable $z = (3x-4y)$ if $E(x) = 1$, $E(y) = 3$, $D(x)=0,4$ $D(y) = 1$ and $Cov(x,y) = - 0,5$
What I'm doing:

First of all, I need to get $3x$ and $4y$. For that, I multiply $D(x) *9$ and $D(y) * 16$ because of the well known formula.

After that, I use formula $Var(x-y) = Var(x) + Var(y) - 2Cov(x,y)$ where $Var(x) = D(x) * 9$ and $Var(y) = D(y) * 16$.

But I got a mistake somewhere. I suppose that I have to change $Cov(x,y)$ as well but I do not know how. Can someone help?

Comment: Your question is too much of a puzzle and needs an edit. How e.g. are $x$ and $y$ defined? What is meant by e.g. $D(a)$? For formatting have a look here: [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @drhab sorry for that. In my case a =x and b =y

Comment: @drhab I changed the notation

Comment: Using the bilinearity of covariance we find:$$\mathsf{Var}\left(3x-4y\right)=\mathsf{Cov}\left(3x-4y,3x-4y\right)=9\mathsf{Cov}\left(x,x\right)-24\mathsf{Cov}\left(x,y\right)+16\mathsf{Cov}\left(y,y\right)=$$$$9\mathsf{Var}\left(x\right)-24\mathsf{Cov}\left(x,y\right)+16\mathsf{Var}\left(y\right)$$Check yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use: $\mathsf{Var}(aX+bY) = \mathsf{Var}(aX)+\mathsf{Var}(bY)+2\mathsf{Cov}(aX,bY)$ , where $a,b$ are constants (respectively: $3$ and $^-4$)

You have correctly determined that $\mathsf{Var}(aX)=a^2\mathsf{Var}(X)$ and $\mathsf{Var}(bY)=b^2\mathsf{Var}(Y)$

Well, likewise, $\mathsf{Cov}(aX, bY)=ab\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)$

So $\mathsf{Var}(3X-4Y) = 9\mathsf{Var}(X)+16\mathsf{Var}(Y)-24\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)$